# Why can't i accept char * as const char *&?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

If I can accept an `char` variable as `const char`& in a function, Why can't I accept a `char*` as a `const char *&` ? 
What I want to do is to have a reference to a pointer with which I am not going to change the data to which it point to, But, to change the location to which the pointer points.

Comment: Simple example code would be useful, with the corresponding error messages

Comment: Why not using simple const char * instead?

Comment: One thing to note, in differentiating your 2 cases: In `const char&`, the `const` is a top level const.  That is to say, it applies to the whole type, which is char.  In `const char*&`, the const is not a top level const.  It doesn't apply to the whole type, which is `char*`, it only applies to the `char`.  A top level const in that case would look like this: `char* const&`.  Consequently, if your parameter type was `char* const&`, it would accept a `char*` as an argument.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think your statements are misleading because references are always "top level const" because they cannot be rebound. There is no reason to view `const` in `const char&` any differently from tha in `const char *`. In both cases `const` apples directly to the `char` part of the declaration. The `const` in `const char &` is not "top level" as can be seen by the fact that `void f(const char&)` and `void f(char&)` are not equivalent function declarations. Of course, an explicit top level `const` on a reference type would be meaningless and is not allowed.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The difference is not between `const char&` and `const char*`, it is between `const char&` and `const char*&`.  There is definitely a reason to view the const differently there.  But perhaps my comments were misleading, because I was looking at things from the point of view of the function accepting the argument.  Let me restate it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: OK, I think I understand. The issue is really about the type being bound, not the reference type itself but as you kept the `&` in your comment while talking about "top level const", I found it somewhat confusing.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Okay, good.  I was having a tough time rephrasing it sensibly, now I don't have to.